# asp.net DataGrid file structure and linking back to it

Tags: asp.net

I am using a DataGrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="articleList" UseAccessibleHeader="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE" HeaderText="File Name">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="DirectoryName" DataTextField="Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="LastWriteTime" HeaderText="Modified" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:f}" />
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Length" HeaderText="Size" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:#,### bytes}" />
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Extension" HeaderText="Type" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Here is my code-behind page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("examfilemanager"));

    articleList.DataSource = dirInfo.GetFiles();
    articleList.DataBind();
}
```

The files inside this directory are:

```
01.jpg
02.jpg
MyDoc.doc
```

I am trying to provide a direct link for the client to click on and download this.  It seems the only links I can get are the name "01.jpg" which is inside a folder examfilemanager.

The Name property of the file info properties returns just the name. (01.jpg)

The href of the link is 01.jpg, I need that to be `examfilemanager/01.jpg` how can i make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Name" 
      DataTextField="Name" 
      HeaderText="File Name"
      DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\examfilemanager\{0}" />
```