# ASP.NET C# Datagrid hyperlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, hyperlink

What I'm trying to do here is have a datagrid show a list of files on the server which the user can click on to download, or open.  The list populates with the files just fine, I get a whole list of all the pdf files in the folder.  When I go to click on them in the datagrid, the link is directed to the application root directory and not to the proper folders.  **How do I tell a datagrid hyperlink column where to go?**

C# code behind:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Assets/reports/");
gridList.DataSource = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf");
gridList.DataBind();
```

asp

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" id="gridList" Font-Name="Verdana"
<Columns>
<asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Name" DataTextField="Name" 
       HeaderText="File Name"/>
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

I tried placing this in:

```
 NavigateUrl =  '<%# "~/Assets/reports/" + Eval("Name") %>'>
```

but I get a "databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a databinding event." error

Comment: When you bind to the files in your first code snippet, what is the actual URL that gets rendered?  Also, if you want to use `Eval()` to build that link then I'd recommend just using a `TemplateColumn` and building a link manually: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479316.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Name" 
  DataTextField="Name" 
  HeaderText="File Name"
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\examfilemanager\{0}" />
```

Found it here.
[asp.net DataGrid file structure and linking back to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177835/asp-net-datagrid-file-structure-and-linking-back-to-it)

Comment: Thanks!  I looked for a solution on here first, but evidently I missed it.